# How can I programmatically install a system service using c# to use a Group Managed Service Account (gMSA)?

Tags: c#, .net, service, installation

I am deploying my company's system in a new environment, and out IT group has given me a list of service accounts to use for each of our system services.  However, they've told me the accounts are [Group Managed Service Accounts](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/) (or gMSAs for short) and there are no passwords since they are managed by the "Key Distribution Service".

I have not worked with gMSAs before, but the source for our installers is quite simple, but it's not working due to the lack of passwords.

```
var process = new ServiceProcessInstaller() {
    Account = ServiceAccount.User,
    Username = <username>,
    Password = <password>,
};
var service = new ServiceInstaller() {
    ServiceName = <code_name>,
    DisplayName = <pretty_name>,
};
service.ServicesDependedOn = <dependencies>;
service.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
service.DelayedAutoStart = true;

Installers.Add(process);
Installers.Add(service);
base.Install(stateSaver);
```

How can I modify my service installers to use an gMSA when no password is given.  I (or another user with admin rights) will be installing the services manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem; there are a couple of things that I needed to change.

First, the username of the account needed to be suffixed with `$`, so instead of `domain\sysuser` it was `domain\sysuser$`.

Next, I had to use `null` as the password instead of `string.Empty`.